# c# session value show by drop down list

Tags: c#, .net, session

I am trying to show the session value by drop down list. This is what the code i made, but its not work well. correct me

```
    //session created

public void SAN()
        {
            cn.Open();
            string sq = "select  Sitealiasname from tbl_Sitemaster where sitename in (select sitename from tbl_emploeedetails where employeestatus='L' and employeeid='" + Session["EMPID"].ToString() + "') and    status='A' order by Sitealiasname asc";
            SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand(sq, cn);
            SqlDataReader r;
            r = d.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                Label4.Text = r["Sitealiasname"].ToString().Trim();
                Session["Sitealiasname"] = Label4.Text;
            }

            cn.Close();

        }


    //call the session to dropdownlist
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlsite.Text = Session["Sitealiasname"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand where SAN() gets called. It has to be called before Page_Load for the Session value to be defined. I would also debug the DB call to make sure the query returns a value...

Comment: Do you want to display session value in your dropdown list?

Comment: will you please state your problem more clearly, the code you have written is doing nothing productive.

Comment: Aravind here you want to show session value in dropdown list?
suppose you have three items 1,2,3 in dropdownlist and session value is 2.then you want 2 in dropdownlist?Is this right ?

Comment: @stay_hungry: Yes friend

Comment: @Sunny: great friend, exactly that is what i want

Comment: @AravindSai,But now you got the answer.Its great :-)

Comment: @Sunny : not ye friend, i didn't got

Comment: But you clicked answered on one answer.

Comment: it was happened by mistakenlky

Comment: So want session value as selected value in dropdownlist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code if i understand exactly what you need then this will work for you.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SAN();
        bind();


    }
}

private void bind()
{
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.Add("first");
    ar.Add("Second");
    ar.Add("Third");
    ar.Add("Four");
    ar.Add("Five");
    ar.Add("Six");
    ar.Add("Seven");
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ar;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["Sitealiasname"].ToString();
}

public void SAN()
    {
        cn.Open();
        string sq = "select  Sitealiasname from tbl_Sitemaster where sitename in (select sitename from tbl_emploeedetails where employeestatus='L' and employeeid='" + Session["EMPID"].ToString() + "') and    status='A' order by Sitealiasname asc";
        SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand(sq, cn);
        SqlDataReader r;
        r = d.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            Label4.Text = r["Sitealiasname"].ToString().Trim();
            Session["Sitealiasname"] = Label4.Text;//Suppose here session value "first"
        }

        cn.Close();

    }
```

let me know if not what you want.

Comment: By using code "first","second","third","forth" bind in the dropdownlist and i assign "second" to session object.On page load i get "Second" as selected value in dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

You can try

For SAN Function Use

```
    List<String> sitenames=null;
    using (DataReader  r = d.ExecuteReader())
    {    
       sitenames = r.AutoMap<string>().ToList();
    }
    Session["Sitealiasname"] = sitenames;
```

For Binding to Dropdownlist you can use

```
    ddlsite.DataSource = Session["Sitealiasname"];
    ddlsite.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

> trying this code in Pageload for Bind Session Value into Dropdowlist

```
ddlsite.Items.Add(Session["Sitealiasname"].Tostring());
```

Comment: i have an item with the drop downlist already friend. some security purpose, i have to sho the item which is equal to the session value

Answer (score 0):

Dropdownlist  does not have text property which you have used here. You have to first populate the dropdown and then select the value which you want to display.

First you should add item in the dropdown by
     items.add()

List of property suppoted by dropdown
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: i have an items with the drop downlist already friend. some security purpose i have to show the item which is equal to the session value

Comment: Ok then use ddlsite.SelctedValue = Session["Sitealiasname"]; to set the value of the session.

Answer (score 0):

try this

// Add  this line
------ Edited-------------

```
using System.Linq;
```

### using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public void SAN()
    {
        cn.Open();
        string sq = "select  Sitealiasname from tbl_Sitemaster where sitename in (select `sitename from tbl_emploeedetails where employeestatus='L' and employeeid='" + Session["EMPID"].ToString() + "') and    status='A' order by Sitealiasname asc";`
        SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand(sq, cn);
        SqlDataReader r;
        r = d.ExecuteReader();
 List<string> sitnames = new  List<string>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            sitename.Add(r["Sitealiasname"].ToString().Trim());
        }

        cn.Close();
Session["Sitealiasname"] = sitename
    }



 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
///Bind data here


if(Session["Sitealiasname"] != null){
       ddlsite.DataSource = Session["Sitealiasname"].ToList();
       ddlsite.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: got error friend " The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly "

Comment: @Aravind Sai Is your issue fixed?

Comment: again got error friend "'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList''